# How to save datetime with tzlocal() into MariaDB?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I'm coming from a Postgres background and am new to MariaDB (MySQL).

When trying to save a DateTime into MariaDB, I'm getting this error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2017-11-25 16:33:26+00:00' for column 'expires_at' at row 1") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO user (username, password, created_at, expires_at, expires_at_ms) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ('uuid1', '...', FakeDatetime(2017, 10, 25, 0, 0), FakeDatetime(2017, 11, 25, 16, 33, 26, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 0)]
```

According to the documentation, I should get around it if I used a TIMESTAMP field instead of DateTime.  But this didn't help either.

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

The issue is this date `'2017-11-25 16:33:26+00:00'`, which is presented like this: `FakeDatetime(2017, 11, 25, 16, 33, 26, tzinfo=tzlocal())`

The fake data comes from `@freeze_time("2017-10-25")` in Python, and shouldn't matter in this context.

**Model in SqlAlchemy:**

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    username = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    created_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP())
    expires_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP())
    expires_at_ms = db.Column(db.BigInteger())
```

**Further analysis:**

```
from dateutil import parser as dt_parser
expires_at = dt_parser.parse('Sat, 25 Nov 2017 16:33:26 GMT')
```

This fails, because MySQL doesn't like tzinfo. 
`datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 25, 16, 33, 26, tzinfo=tzlocal())`

But `expires_at = datetime.datetime.now()` works. Because this is acceptable for MySQL: `datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 2, 9, 44, 55, 392927)`

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB does not handle `+00:00`, nor `GMT`.

Comment: Not even the TIMESTAMP type? So do I have to convert them? How exactly?